# How to remove check icon in multi_select_flutter with material 3

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using multi_select_flutter package with material 3. After selecting the item, there is check icon displayed in the bottom chip.

[image]

When I set useMaterial3: false, the check icon doesn't appear.

[image]

Can anybody help me out how to remove the check icon while still using material 3?

Comment: set showCheckBox to false

Comment: if you set useMaterial3 to false it will use Material 2 appearance and its default settings which has a different showCheckBox

Comment: I want to use material 3 as default. I've already tried to change the global checkmark to false on chiptheme. Nothing's happening.

Answer (score -1):

*This may not be a **good** solution, But if you want **shortcut** way, you can do like this*

```
child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(),
        child: ChoiceChip(),
       )
```